# Can PWA read photo geolocation from IOS photo library on upload?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I know IOS strips out that info for uploads on regular websites, but was wondering if it's the same case with the PWAs.

I'm trying to figure out whether I should build a PWA (preferred) or do I need to make a native app to be able to have users upload photos **with** the geotags.

I appreciate any info. I couldn't find answer to this question anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the iOS that it removes the Geolocation Info from the  images uploaded.
But you can chech and try out using sample / demo project that helps you to upload an image.

Their is a library called exif.js which you can use for extracting the geolocation on the webpage for the photos being uploaded so their is no required for the backend.

If your are getting the geolocation info on image upload then you can use that info.

Here is a link for the same. https://awik.io/extract-gps-location-exif-data-photos-using-javascript/